# how to download pdf option in angular typescript 12

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

hello i'm using angular typescript 12
and i want to download pdf while clicking on a Button
for the moment i used jsPDF but the style and the color of the content gets ruined inside the pdf

since the style i did for my page works really fine testing it inside in another place but it gets ruiend only in pdf mode

using this code :

```
  downloadPDF()
  {
    let pdf=new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
    pdf.html(this.el.nativeElement,{
      callback:(pdf)=>{
        pdf.save("invoice.pdf");
      }
    });


  }
```

is there any way i can use to adjust my style or even changing using jsPDF to anothereasiest way .

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to establish that on the client-side only. Warning, this is opinionated (though probably the only sensible option at the moment): Set up a NodeJS api that can use Puppeteer to render any HTML page and print it virtually as PDF. TLDR: Puppeteer is a library that enables you to render any URL in a headless Chromium browser on the server-side, manipulate it as you will, and "print" the result into PDF if you need to.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer